# Como corregir Warning de: Notice: Undefined index al guardar formulario

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tengo un incidente cuando guardo los datos del formulario ya que me presenta un "Notice", lo curioso es que si me guarda los datos del formulario este es mi código:

```js
<?php
session_start();

/* Inicia validacion del lado del servidor */
if (empty($_POST['sheets'])) {
$errors[] = "Páginas vacío";
} else if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
$errors[] = "Asunto vacío";
} else if (
    !empty($_POST['sheets']) &&
    !empty($_POST['title'])
) {
include "../config/config.php"; //Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos        

$title = $_POST["title"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$sender_id = $_POST["sender_id"];
$kind_id = $_POST["kind_id"];
$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$project_id = $_POST["project_id"];
$category_id = $_POST["category_id"];
$priority_id = $_POST["priority_id"];
$status_id = $_POST["status_id"];
$attach_id = $_POST["attach_id"];
$paginas = $_POST["sheets"];
$created_at = "NOW()";
$filecase = $_POST["filecase_id"];
$way = $_POST["way_id"];
$received = $_POST["received"];
$user_received = $_POST['user_received'];
$file = empty($_POST["file"]) ? "" : $_POST["file"];
$craft = $_POST['craft'];
$datecraft = $_POST['craftdatetimepicker'];

if ((isset($_POST['mostrar']) != 1) && (isset($_POST['mostrar1']) != 1 )) {

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) as cont FROM document WHERE year(created_at)=year(now())");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $cont = $row['cont'] + 1; // incrementa   
        $num = sprintf("%'.05d", $cont); // formato con 5 digitos
        $codigo = date("Y") . "-" . $num; // se concatena con el año actual
    }

    $code = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = $category_id");

    if ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($code)) {
        $cont1 = $f['code'];
        $codigo1 = $num . "-" . date("Y") . "-" . $cont1; // se concatena con el año actual        
    }

    if (isset($_POST["user_id"])) {
        $sel = '';
        foreach ($_POST["user_id"] as $row) {
            $sel .= $row . ', ';
        }
        $sel = substr($sel, 0, -2);
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST["project_id"])) {
        $project = '';
        foreach ($_POST["project_id"] as $row) {
            $project .= $row . ', ';
        }
        $project = substr($project, 0, -2);
    }

    $sql = "insert into document (consecutive,file,filecase_id,title,description,sender_id,kind_id,user_id,project_id,category_id,assigned_to,priority_id,status_id,attach_id,sheets,created_at, way_id, received, user_received) value (\"$codigo\",\"$codigo1\",\"$filecase\",\"$title\",\"$description\",\"$sender_id\",$kind_id,$user_id,\"$project\",\"$category_id\",\"$sel\",$priority_id,$status_id,$attach_id,$paginas,$created_at, $way, \"$received\", \"$user_received\")";
} elseif ((isset($_POST['mostrar']) == 1) && (isset($_POST['mostrar1']) != 1 )) {

    $check_new = 0;

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) as cont FROM document WHERE year(created_at)=year(now())");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $cont = $row['cont'] + 1; // incrementa   
        $num = sprintf("%'.05d", $cont); // formato con 5 digitos
        $codigo = date("Y") . "-" . $num; // se concatena con el año actual
    }

    $code1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM document WHERE id = $file");

    if ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($code1)) {
        $cont2 = $f['file'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST["user_id"])) {
        $sel = '';
        foreach ($_POST["user_id"] as $row) {
            $sel .= $row . ', ';
        }
        $sel = substr($sel, 0, -2);
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST["project_id"])) {
        $project = '';
        foreach ($_POST["project_id"] as $row) {
            $project .= $row . ', ';
        }
        $project = substr($project, 0, -2);
    }

    $sql = "insert into document (consecutive,file,filecase_id,title,description,sender_id,kind_id,user_id,project_id,category_id,assigned_to,priority_id,status_id,attach_id,sheets,created_at, way_id, received, user_received, check_new) value (\"$codigo\",\"$cont2\",\"$filecase\",\"$title\",\"$description\",\"$sender_id\",$kind_id,$user_id,\"$project\",\"$category_id\",\"$sel\",$priority_id,$status_id,$attach_id,$paginas,$created_at, $way, \"$received\", \"$user_received\", \"$check_new\")";
} elseif ((isset($_POST['mostrar']) != 1) && (isset($_POST['mostrar1']) == 1 )) {

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) as cont FROM document WHERE year(created_at)=year(now())");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $cont = $row['cont'] + 1; // incrementa   
        $num = sprintf("%'.05d", $cont); // formato con 5 digitos
        $codigo = date("Y") . "-" . $num; // se concatena con el año actual
    }

    $code = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = $category_id");

    if ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($code)) {
        $cont1 = $f['code'];
        $codigo1 = $num . "-" . date("Y") . "-" . $cont1; // se concatena con el año actual        
    }

    if (isset($_POST["user_id"])) {
        $sel = '';
        foreach ($_POST["user_id"] as $row) {
            $sel .= $row . ', ';
        }
        $sel = substr($sel, 0, -2);
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST["project_id"])) {
        $project = '';
        foreach ($_POST["project_id"] as $row) {
            $project .= $row . ', ';
        }
        $project = substr($project, 0, -2);
    }

    $sql = "insert into document (consecutive,file,filecase_id,title,description,sender_id,kind_id,user_id,project_id,category_id,assigned_to,priority_id,status_id,attach_id,sheets,created_at, way_id, received, user_received, craft, datecraft) value (\"$codigo\",\"$codigo1\",\"$filecase\",\"$title\",\"$description\",\"$sender_id\",$kind_id,$user_id,\"$project\",\"$category_id\",\"$sel\",$priority_id,$status_id,$attach_id,$paginas,$created_at, $way, \"$received\", \"$user_received\", \"$craft\", \"$datecraft\")";
} else {

    $check_new = 0;

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) as cont FROM document WHERE year(created_at)=year(now())");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $cont = $row['cont'] + 1; // incrementa   
        $num = sprintf("%'.05d", $cont); // formato con 5 digitos
        $codigo = date("Y") . "-" . $num; // se concatena con el año actual
    }

    $code1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM document WHERE id = $file");

    if ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($code1)) {
        $cont2 = $f['file'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST["user_id"])) {
        $sel = '';
        foreach ($_POST["user_id"] as $row) {
            $sel .= $row . ', ';
        }
        $sel = substr($sel, 0, -2);
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST["project_id"])) {
        $project = '';
        foreach ($_POST["project_id"] as $row) {
            $project .= $row . ', ';
        }
        $project = substr($project, 0, -2);
    }

    $sql = "insert into document (consecutive,file,filecase_id,title,description,sender_id,kind_id,user_id,project_id,category_id,assigned_to,priority_id,status_id,attach_id,sheets,created_at, way_id, received, user_received, check_new, craft, datecraft) value (\"$codigo\",\"$cont2\",\"$filecase\",\"$title\",\"$description\",\"$sender_id\",$kind_id,$user_id,\"$project\",\"$category_id\",\"$sel\",$priority_id,$status_id,$attach_id,$paginas,$created_at, $way, \"$received\", \"$user_received\", \"$check_new\", \"$craft\", \"$datecraft\")";
}

$query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if ($query_new_insert) {
    $messages[] = "Tu documento ha sido ingresado satisfactoriamente.";
} else {
    $errors [] = "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente." . mysqli_error($con);
}
} else {
$errors [] = "Error desconocido.";
}

if (isset($errors)) {
?>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Error!</strong> 
<?php
foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo $error;
}
?>
</div>
    <?php
}

if (isset($messages)) {
    ?>
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
<?php
foreach ($messages as $message) {
    echo $message;
}
?>
</div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Me da este anuncio: 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\SysCPC\action\adddocument.php on line 83

Notice: Undefined variable: cont2 in C:\wamp64\www\SysCPC\action\adddocument.php on line 103

Comment: ¿Cómo estás enviando los datos desde el formulario? El Warning parece indicar que el valor del select cuyo `name` es `selectpicker` no se está enviando... De todos modos, todo lo que se recupera por POST o por GET debería ser evaluado de alguna forma para evitar eso precisamente. Puedes usar `isset` o `empty` para ello.

Comment: Podría agregar un ejemplo mas practico

Comment: Una forma que me parece particularmente práctica es usar operadores ternarios al asignar las variables. Por ejemplo: `$title = empty($_POST["title"]) ? "" : $_POST["title"]);` En ese caso, si no hay nada en el POST, la variable tomará un valor vacío, de lo contrario tomará el valor de ese POST y evitarás al mismo tiempo el `Notice Undefined Index`. Sería cuestión de hacerlo con cada una de las variables que tomas del POST...